# Update column with random values within a range

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite database and I'm populating sample data into my tables. The sample data needs a little messaging if the related data is going work properly, i.e. I need to start putting in primary and foreign keys in my tables.

First question is, how do I update the projectID column in my Project table for all the rows so that each row number is the value stored in the projectID field. I want this to be sequential and update the index.

```
update "project" set "projectID"= Count(*)
```

Second question is, I have to also update the customerID foreign key field in the project table. The only problem with this is, I want it to update between values 1 through to 50 and I want the rows to be updated randomly. Is this possible with sql, or am I going to have to export the data out of sqlite and process in a third party application and reimport.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To get the row number, use the [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid):

   ```
   UPDATE project SET projectID = rowid;
   ```
2. The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#random) says:

   > The random() function returns a pseudo-random integer between -9223372036854775808 and +9223372036854775807.

   So to get values between 1 and 50, scale and offset these values appropriately:

   ```
   UPDATE project SET customerID = CAST(abs(random()) / 184467440737095517 AS INTEGER) + 1;
   ```

Comment: Thanks, the random statement for customerID worked a treat, the update to projectID seem to execute, but didn't update. Ive now manually updated the projectID.